# SAP data access through .NET application

Tags: .net, sap-gui

I need a targeted set of data out of SAP ERP system (SAP GUI TCode `MB51`).  I know there are better paths to get at the data, but my rights are very limited.  I can't call BAPI transaction to interrogate the BAPI calls.  I've been able to automate what I want using an active x script, referencing `SAPFEWSE.ocx`.

Internally the SAP team has been less than supportive of what we are attempting to do and have offered a job spooled up at some interval to dump a text file.

Assuming my access is limited to the TCodes I need, what is the best way to extract this data in to my application?  While `SAPFEWSE.ocx` worked, this will eventually turn into a Windows service to monitor the data when needed.

Comment: Primary choice: Have your bosses escalate the business needs to a point where you will get the IT support you need so you won't have to apply any kind of ugly hacks to a mission-critical ERP system. Since that's a non-technical solution, I won't add it as an answer...

Comment: Fair enough, was hoping there was some way to utilize transaction calls to get data out of SAP in a automated way.